# Popup screen position change in blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, keyboard, popup, popupwindow

when i click on `Buttonfield` i want to show `Popup screen` .everything working fine .but that `PopupScreen` open by default at the center of the `Mainscreen`.

i have already try this code.`setMargin` and `setPosstion` method to change the possition. but its not working as my requrement .

i want to open that `Popupscreen` at the top of `Mainscreen` with Animation(top to bottom).

and another issue is that in this popup screen there is one Edittextfield ..when i click on edittext field keyboard open fine but at that time device `Menu` button not working and i cant access keyborad hide functionality ..

how to set popup screen at the top of the mainscreen ?

Comment: When a screen is a popupScreen the Menu option doesn't work. And I think we don't have any functionality to put a popup screen at any position. You can open a screen from top to bottom or left to right. Do you want a requirement as when popup is open Menu should be work?

Comment: i havnt requrement to open Menu when my popupscreen open  but my popupscreen have one textfield and Go button .. when i click on textfield default keyboard open successfully but i cant it hide because  i cant access any Menu option from simulator as well as device . so how to enable this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried overriding the sublayout() method in the popupScreen class ?

```
protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {

        super.sublayout(width, height);

       // replace x,y with your values //

        setPosition(x, y);

    }
```

HOWEVER, if you are trying to animate the popup screen from top to bottom, you are better off using EyelidFieldManager, it does the animation for you :)

Try:

[EyelidFieldManager Sample](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Display_fields_on_a_temp_pair_of_managers_839920_11.jsp)

[EyelidFieldManager API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/extension/container/EyelidFieldManager.html)

Comment: thanx @Bhavik its wotking to change position of the popupscreen ...my popup screen height around 100 than how can i give animation from top to bottom ?

Comment: @Coder, a quick and dirty way to do it would be using a timer  function in the popup screen that changes the x,y values and then calls updateLayout(). Keep in mind that in the run method of the your TimerTask class you will need to use InvokeAndWait. [Timer Example](http://www.gammelsaeter.com/programming/simple-timer-example-in-java/)